# Unknown URL type using urllib2.urlopen()

Tags: python, csv, urllib2

I am trying to do the following:

- open a CSV file containing a list with URLs (GET-Requests)
- read the CSV file and write the entries to a list
- open every single URL and read the answer
- write the answers back to a new CSV file

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\l.buinui\Desktop\request2.py", line 16, in <module>
    req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 427, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1247, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: ['http>
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import csv

# Open and read the source file and write entries to a list called link_list
source_file=open("source_new.csv", "rb")
source = csv.reader(source_file, delimiter=";")
link_list = [row for row in source]
source_file.close()

# Create an output file which contains the answer of the GET-Request
out=open("output.csv", "wb")
output = csv.writer(out, delimiter=";")
for row in link_list:
    url = str(row)
    req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    output.writerow(req.read())

out.close()
```

What is going wrong there?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Cheers

Comment: looks like your `url` var looks like this: `['http://some.host/path`. you have unneeded symbols in the beginning of string.

Comment: I also thought this could be the problem. But even if I replace "[" and "'" at the beginning and at the end, the problem is still the same.

Comment: can you print the `url` before loading it?

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly as you wrote before: `['http://example.com']`

Comment: Can you give a sample of CSV data?

Comment: I cannot disclose the original link list but every entry (row) in the CSV file looks similar to the following: `https://service.blabla.com/webservice/index.php?user=4711&pass=johnny=Max&na=Mustermann&str=blabla&ip=199.299.299.399`

Comment: I mean can you show is represented the data? Does a row contain only an url? Is it limited by double cotes, is there a semicolon at end of a line?

Comment: Can you print `row`? is it `['http://example.com']`? so `url` would be `"['http://example.com']"`, isn't it?

Comment: I just edited a properly working version above. Thanks for your comments. The solution seems kind of strange to me but finally it works. Does anybody know how to convert a string in order to get umlauts displayed correctly?

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow. How can I mark a thread as "solved"?

Answer (score 0):

Using the row variable will pass a list element (it contains only one element, the url) to urlopen, but passing row[0] will pass the string containing the url.

The `csv.reader` returns a list for each row it reads, no matter how many items are in the row.

Comment: If you read the comments of the question you will see that the problem was already fixed.

Comment: yes, I saw that, but you seemed a bit confused about the solution, hope that explains it better and also, you can't select a comment as a solution, only an answer.

Comment: We were not confused. He put in his question the answer but it was maybe not clear.

Comment: Thanks, guys. @ojs: Thanks for the explanation. In order to make it clear that the question is answered, I will formally create an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. If I directly reference `row[0]`in the loop there are no problems.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import csv

# Open and read the source file and write entries to a list called link_list
source_file=open("source.csv", "rb")
source = csv.reader(source_file, delimiter=";")
link_list = [row for row in source]
source_file.close()

# Create an output file which contains the answer of the GET-Request
out=open("output.csv", "wb")
output = csv.writer(out)
for row in link_list:
    req = urllib2.urlopen(row[0])
    answer = req.read()
    output.writerow([answer])


out.close()
```